# After google+ integration on android how can I save user activities

Tags: android, database, api, google-plus

I have successfully integrated Google+ api on my Android app, but I still can't figure out how to save my user in-app activity, like the user test scores, user high scores and tgung of that type. I know how to get their data like profile picture and other. All I need is how to save their activity in my app.
Will I need some database or something. 
I hope someone can help.